# Directly send an bare HCI_ACL packet

Tags: bluetooth, mitmproxy

Could someone tell me that is it possible to send an bare HCI_ACL bluetooth packet directly without any upper data layer contains in it?
Or could someone tell me is there any MITMproxy for bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The bluetooth stack is based on abstraction layers, you cannot arbitrarily remove layers and expect it to work.